# Resolving Maven dependency conflicts?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Given my following `pom.xml` in Eclipse Mars.1 with m2e plugin:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.mytools</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-tool</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <properties>
      <jmeter-version>2.13</jmeter-version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.4</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I update the Maven dependencies they are all present. However I have an awful lots of conflicts between versions if I inspect the dependency hierarchy, see the screenshot. How can I resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: which kind of conflicts?

Comment: Updated my question with two screenshots.

Comment: You should take a look at those where artifactid is equal like `commons-jexl` and explicitly define the version in your pom you would like to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having searched I found that this is a bug in the POM for `org.apache.jorphan:2.13`. Please see this link for details: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57734

As a workaround the following POM with exclusions works in my case:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
  <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <properties>
      <jmeter.version>2.13</jmeter.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
          <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-math3</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool2</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```